# Passing an Array of pointers to 3D arrays: Access violation exception (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am working on a C++ minecraft clone where Chunk objects keep a list of pointers to their adjacent chunks (neighbors). A chunk can have a maximum of 6 neighbors, but if a chunk has no neighbor on one side, the element in the array on that side is a nullptr. Chunks have 3D arrays of Block structs, which have one data member: type (int). Chunks pass their blocks, and an array of pointers to the blocks of their neighbors, into a renderer:

```
Block (*neighbor_blocks[6])[CHUNK_SIZE][CHUNK_SIZE][CHUNK_SIZE];

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (neighbors[i] == nullptr) {
        neighbor_blocks[i] = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        neighbor_blocks[i] = &(neighbors[i]->blocks);
    }
}

renderer.gen_buffer(blocks, neighbor_blocks);
```

The signature of the method it calls looks like this:

```
void BlockRenderer::gen_buffer(Block blocks[CHUNK_SIZE][CHUNK_SIZE][CHUNK_SIZE], Block (*neighbor_blocks[6])[CHUNK_SIZE][CHUNK_SIZE][CHUNK_SIZE]);
```

I believe that this makes an array of pointers to my 3D Block arrays:

```
Block (*neighbor_blocks[6])[CHUNK_SIZE][CHUNK_SIZE][CHUNK_SIZE])
```

To test my array of pointers I did the following:

```
if (neighbor_blocks[4] != nullptr) {
    printf("%d\n", neighbor_blocks[4][0][0][0]->type);
}
```

Every element in the blocks array is initialized with a block, so calling blocks[0][0][0] on any chunk should not be a problem, and as you saw, every neighbor_blocks element was either initialized with a nullptr or given a pointer to the blocks array of a chunk. However, my print line sometimes results in this exception:

0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x003F63D8.

Is my method to make an array of pointers to 3D arrays correct? Am I accessing the data there correctly? The exception is sometimes not thrown, suggesting to me that I am accessing the wrong memory, and sometimes I can access whatever I am accessing, but sometimes it is not accessible to my program.

Comment: Looks like mostly C code to me. Perhaps you want to use C++ things like classes and vectors and smart pointers and encapsulation and stuff.

Comment: There's a bug in your code

Comment: OMG, he's a 5 star coder.  I never thought I would see the day that such glory was manifest before me.  http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).